# Infer callback argument from type parameter

Tags: typescript

I wrote a React hook that adds an event listener to an event target with automatic cleanup. The implementation is fairly simple, but I’m having issues with the type definitions.

I created the following working implementation.

```js
type Listener<E extends Event = Event> = (event: E) => void;
type Options = boolean | AddEventListenerOptions;

function useEventListener<K extends keyof DocumentEventMap>(
  target: Document,
  type: K,
  listener: Listener<DocumentEventMap[K]>,
  options?: Options,
): void;
function useEventListener<T extends HTMLElement, K extends keyof HTMLElementEventMap>(
  target: T,
  type: K,
  listener: Listener<HTMLElementEventMap[K]>,
  options?: Options,
): void;
function useEventListener(
  target: EventTarget,
  type: string,
  listener: Listener,
  options?: Options,
): void;
function useEventListener(
  target: EventTarget,
  type: string,
  listener: Listener,
  options?: Options,
): void {
  useEffect(() => {
    target.addEventListener(type, listener, options);

    return () => target.removeEventListener(type, listener, options);
  }, [listener, options, target, type]);
}

function onClick(event: MouseEvent) {}

useEventListener(document, 'click', onClick);
```

However, this means all acceptable event targets need to be added explicitly. It would be much nicer if this could be deferred automatically. I tried the following:

```js
function useEventListener<T extends EventTarget>(
  target: T,
  type: Parameters<EventTarget['addEventListener']>[0],
  listener: Parameters<EventTarget['addEventListener']>[1],
  options?: Parameters<EventTarget['addEventListener']>[2]
): void {}

function onClick(event: MouseEvent) {}

useEventListener(document, 'click', onClick);
```

… but this throws an error.

Can I defer the event listener type from the event target passed in for **any** type of event target?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=44&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAMglgZ2BAdhATgHgKJQgD2RQBMEpsA3VYKAXnKpWAD46oAKCR4ALnIEo6rCgHs4xANwAoUJCgB5MMDgiUZegCMRIgDYQAhiigAfKAEFixStXhJUGRctUJpUgGYBXFAGMnRjwgQ1ky2RBiYANJ4hKikUADWECAiblAAIiLeHgC21MHAALL6YMzsUlBQwProAOYQvOmZOdQANOWV4BB8EW0VOohh6Hyh9lgZWblM+UVgANoRALrMvVAiSipqAPx8jhsIbfx8ouLSnj5+UAFB3CNoWAAq0URxABL3BTDYepPALVBRBGeZESyVSbw+XwgP2mxVK7SqtXqfHuK1kXX+K36djuwwGo0w4M+3zy3Bm8yWKzWfgQ2wU62cByOYkk7i8vg2l0C+VuGDKFQRdQa+Xu1UFqM6fCQ6DgKBqmLxONgCowlPpWx2av2UkOUGOLLO7NUnOuNmV6D5lVFSIY1BFiN+8IlUClMrl7Sxg1x2JV7Spe1puwZ2qZ4igAG8AL5SVnnDmqADC-W88U43D4BREV3ygjDUCjUizNzN7GITR+fwA5N4k-EK38EzX+K4Y4b-Fyi970AAmTCPQGxMjCq0sC0C60ox2QPgABWq+lyyHQCBw3DtgtmFf0lm5ZorS1mAAYFvLOzO5wuMMuh-aN1urB3BnvmLMAIzH32a2mz9Dz+qXle2sOt7bg+oxPrMXYLMGurMuG+bRoWpqdl2JZlq0UBVjWdarCgiZwMmTZSEAA)

Comment: I doubt you'll get this to work automatically because the compiler doesn't really infer from overloads the way you want.  `document.addEventListener` is an overloaded function and `Parameters` will infer from the last overload (see [the doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types)).  And even if it could pick the right overload; it's generic, so I don't think the compiler would be able to do the higher-order generic inference needed here.

Comment: Reminded of [microsoft/TypeScript#30887](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30887) and [microsoft/TypeScript#33185](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33185) for this lack of inferring generic function parameters.  I think your first implementation is the cleanest thing you can do here.  I'm happy to write this up as an answer unless someone finds a more promising approach?

Comment: This is not the answer I was hoping for, but it’s good to know. I’ll stick with my initial solution then. Thanks for the feedback!